# String or binary data would be truncated error despite inserting the string value within the given length

Tags: sql

```
create table Sample
(
Student_Name varchar,
Student_ID int,
Student_major char(20)
)

insert into Sample values ('Sai',1001,'Computer Science')
```

Messages:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Comment: Define a size for Student_Name sth like Student_Name varchar(10)

Comment: Even after modifying the Student_Name with a specific size say varchar(10) the error still remains...any help please...I don't understand why the error String or binary data would be truncated still arives.

Comment: The number of characters you are trying to insert should not be greater than the size you specified in your table definition.

Comment: create table Sample1
(
Student_Name varchar(10),
Student_ID int,
Student_major char(10)
) 

insert into Sample1 values ('Sam',1001,'Computer Science')

Messages:
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Please refer to my last comment: 'Computer Science' is now greater than 10

Comment: Yeah, I've checked it thank you...:) Also, would like to know that do we generally need to specify the size of the varchar while creating tables?
As we know that varchar itself is flexible...why does it not get executed when we don't specify the length of the varchar???

Comment: You always need to specify the length of VARCHAR but if you want it to be flexible you can use VARCHAR(MAX) but it's not recommended in terms of performance and capacity.

Comment: please update your question and tag of your dbms like `sql-server` as I think is that. and say the version of that in your question .... all because of your codes should run without any error with these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get this error message

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated

It means the length of the column you have specified in your table is less the value you are trying to insert

So in your case you need to define a length for all of your string datatypes and in your `INSERT` statement, number of characters should not be greater than length of datatype.

```
create table Sample
(
 Student_Name varchar(20),
 Student_ID int,
 Student_major char(20)
)
```

Comment: You can vote it up and mark it as answer if it helped.